Allow sort specification in site search
I regularly look for new Delphi question in [SO], using is:q delphi
When the results are displayed, I have to cick Newest
It would be nice if sort options could be added to the search query. What comes to mind is
is:q delphi sort:newest, maybe with the abbreviation is:q delphi sort:n

Similar for the other sort options Relevance ('r') and Score ('s')

'newest' should refer to the creation datetime, not the last datetime the question was updated


If anyone knows of an alternative way (e.g. modifying the URL), that would be nice too...

When I click the Newest button the URL changes to:
https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=is%3aq%20delphi&searchOn=3

So it looks like adding &searchOn=3 to the URL works as well.
Now to remember that... ;-)

No. The "searchOn" is something related to Teams, and it's already requested to remove it on the regular sites. What determines the sort is the tab=newest parameter in  the URL. But it does not answer the question here, which asks for a way to have it before searching, not after.
